# Ubuntu installation erased whole hard drive?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows

I have a laptop that comes with Windows 8 pre-installed and I have installed Ubuntu alongside it.
I was trying to re-install Ubuntu using a DVD and on the installation panel I choose "Delete Ubuntu 14.10 and install Ubuntu 14.04" - later on the installation failed leaving me with no bootable OS and now even the DVD doesn't boot , all i get is a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I haven't tried anything to avoid further damage...

What should I do

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu